# Mainframe to Outlook

Tags: html, email, mainframe

I would like to send reports from the Mainframe (z/OS) to Outlook 2016  I would like to properly format the report.  I don't know HTML, but if someone can help me with some simple **basic commands just to get the report to line up** and be evenly spaced  as it looks on the mainframe, that would help. Attachments are how it looks on the mainframe and how it looks in Outlook [image: green screen] [image: email text]

```
this is the requested Jcl  - step004 removes the low values x'00' and replaces with spaces  the email step emails the file to outlook 
//STEP004  EXEC PGM=SORT                                               
//SORTIN   DD DSN=HGT.SDCPROD.REPORT1,                                 
//            DISP=SHR                                                 
//SORTOUT  DD DSN=HGT.SDCPROD.REPORT2,                                 
//            DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),                                    
//            UNIT=DTA,SPACE=(TRK,(10,5),RLSE),                        
//            DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=132,BLKSIZE=27984)                   
//SORTXSUM DD SYSOUT=*,DCB=LRECL=132                                   
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                                 
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                                 
//SYSUDUMP DD SYSOUT=*                                                 
//SYSABEND DD SYSOUT=*                                                 
//SYSIN    DD *                                                        
  SORT FIELDS=COPY                                                     
  ALTSEQ CODE=(0040)                                                   
  OUTREC FIELDS=(1,132,TRAN=ALTSEQ)                                    
//*******************************************************************  
//EMAILIT EXEC HTMLMAIX,EPARMS='*'                  
//SYSIN DD *                                        
MIME-VERSION: 1.0                                   
CONTENT-TYPE: TEXT/HTML                             
SUBJECT='SYSTEM DATA COPY PRODUCTION REPORT'        
EMAILADR=DEREZ_LUSK@BCBSIL.COM                      
EMAILCPY=DEREZ_LUSK@BCBSIL.COM                      
EMAILDSN='HGT.SDCPROD.REPORT2'                      
STATUS='COMPLETED'                                  
/*                                                  
//
```

Comment: How are you sending the report via email? Is this an automated process (e.g., SYSOUT=* from a batch job run)? A little more info here can help provide you with a more complete answer.

Comment: //PS060 EXEC EMAILIT,EPARMS='HCMSGEN.HCSC.MONTANA.CONTROL(SDCPRODE)
 sdcprode member                                                                                                    CONTENT-TYPE: TEXT/HTML; CHARSET="US-ASCII"    
<HTML>                                         
<FONT COLOR="RED" FACE="COURIER NEW" SIZE="12">
<BODY>                                          
EMAILDSN='HGT.SDCPROD.REPORT2'                 
</BODY>                                        
</FONT>                                        
</HTML>

Comment: I realize that line breaks are an issue; can you please put both the JCL and the expanded JCL in code tags in the question?

Comment: there is a 585 char limit for this  comment.  so the step //PS060  the file is  HCMSGEN.HCSC.MONTANA.CONTROL(SDCPRODE)   in the SDCPRODE member I have the above html  tags  as shown in the previous comment

Comment: Please edit your question and put the requested information  there, not in a comment. It is unreadable in a comment.

Comment: updated coments @zarchasmpgmr

Comment: Thank you. This will help those who find this question in the future.

Comment: If you have any documentation regarding the program inside the HTMLMAIX PROC (look at the EXEC PGM= from the JCL listing, it will be helpful to know that), it should instruct you how to send it as a text or in monospaced font. The name of the PROC signals to me that it is meant to generate HTML format mail by default. There are several other methods, including a couple built into z/OS. that send plain text by default. There is also the excellent XMITIP utility by Lionel Dyck (see http://www.lbdsoftware.com/).

Answer (score 2):

@derez,  Did you tried sending your report as ".txt" attachment ?

in JCL provide the attachment detail's like below,

```
MIME-VERSION: 1.0   
CONTENT-TYPE: TEXT/PLAIN;                                               
CONTENT-DISPOSITION: ATTACHMENT; FILENAME="PRODUCTION_REPORT.TXT"
```

Comment: @Karthik   I will check if the users will accept an attachment

Answer (score 1):

1. I used the following records,

   ```
      JOB      EXECUTION TIME  JOB NUM DAY MON YEAR START  END     RT CD
   HGDSDCIO    20180824030522   23017  24  AUG 2018 03.05  03.05    00  
   HGDSDCIO    20180824030522   23017  24  AUG 2018 03.05  03.05    00
   ```
2. Used Syncsort to add `PUT "`  and `";` at the leading & trailing areas of the records using following `SYSIN` statements.

   ```
   SORT FIELDS=COPY                                              
   OUTREC FIELDS=(1:C'PUT ',5:X'7F',6:1,69,75:X'7F',76:C';',80:X)
   ```

   Output from 2nd step:

   ```
   PUT "   JOB      EXECUTION TIME  JOB NUM DAY MON YEAR START  END     RT CD";
   PUT "HGDSDCIO    20180824030522   23017  24  AUG 2018 03.05  03.05    00  ";
   PUT "HGDSDCIO    20180824030522   23017  24  AUG 2018 03.05  03.05    00  ";
   ```
3. And used the following SAS step to send email.

   ```
   //STEP01   EXEC  SASPROD  
   //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*    
   //EMAIL DD SYSOUT=(B,SMTP)
   //SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*    
   //SYSIN DD *              
   OPTIONS EMAILSYS="SMTP" EMAILHOST="*smtp server name*";               
   FILENAME OUTBOX EMAIL;                   
   DATA _NULL_;                                                           
   FILE OUTBOX                                                         
      TO=("xxx@yyy.com")                              
      SUBJECT="SAS MAIL TEST"                                          
      TYPE="TEXT/PLAIN";
      PUT "   JOB      EXECUTION TIME  JOB NUM DAY MON YEAR START  END     RT CD";
      PUT "HGDSDCIO    20180824030522   23017  24  AUG 2018 03.05  03.05    00  ";
      PUT "HGDSDCIO    20180824030522   23017  24  AUG 2018 03.05  03.05    00  ";
      RUN;
   ```
4. Got the following in email.

[image: Email contents]

You've already mentioned that the report will be different every time as different jobs run on different days. This method will still work, if you concatenate the following 3 files (in order) & pass it in SYSIN to the SAS step.

1. File with SAS statements from line 1 till  `TYPE="TEXT/PLAIN";` in one dataset.
2. File with PUT statements in one dataset
3. File with `RUN;` in one dataset.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Srinivasan Jv  it will try using the SAS ...and see if it formats correctly in outlook

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to get a copy of XMITIP from https://github.com/lbdyck/xmitip or https://www.cbttape.com file 314.

This application comes with an optional ISPF dialog with a lot of capabilities to generate SMTP emails from z/OS.

One use is to use the ISPF dialog to generate the command and then copy and use the generated JCL in your batch job.

Answer (score -1):

First, this has nothing to do with the mainframe; it's an HTML question.  You've got a couple of issues here:  first, you have to make sure you're using a fixed width font, and after that, you probably want to use tables.

So, something like this:

```html
<pre>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
Header Information
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
Column1
</td>
<td align="center">
Column 2
</td>
<td align="center">
Column 3
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center">ABCEFGH</td>
<td align="center">201812345678</td>
<td align="center">Stuff</td>
</tr>

</table>

</pre>
```

Comment: thanks Kevin  but since the report is different every time as different jobs run on different days  Not sure if this will work  based on the number of rows

Comment: Also @Kevin Mc Kenzie...  how do i get the data in the table.   This is Mainframe COBOL,  I can easily build the header and column names,  but what about the actual data that is stored in variables